# How to check if an attribute is present in an element using Java?

Tags: java

There is a form with 4 input fields. When any one of the input fields is kept blank and the submit button is clicked, an error popup is displayed for the respective field mentioned in the error text. Whenever any field is NOT kept blank and the submit button is clicked, an attribute 'value' is added to the field tag.

I want to count the number of fields that are kept blank after clicking on the submit button.

My code:

```
public int getcountBlankFields()
{ int count=0;
  if(txt_Field1.getAttribute("value")==null)
    { count++; }
  if(txt_Field2.getAttribute("value")==null)
    { count++; }
  return count;
}
```

count does not increase as the condition is not getting verified. Can someone give me Java code to find if a particular attribute exists in an element?

Comment: I am using Selenium WebDriver & txt_Field1 is a WebElement

Comment: Java and JavaScript are two completely different languages. Your code is Java and not JavaScript.

Comment: The value of `input type="text"` or `textarea` is never `null`, it's always a string, might be an empty string, though.

Comment: Have checked `txt_Field1.getAttribute("value").length==0)` still not working. I need JavaScript to locate the attribute exists or not

Answer (score 0):

Convert your above code to Javascript. Below code will give the glance of how it should be.

And yes you are mixing two languages. Java is not same as Javascript.

Key differences between Java and JavaScript:

- Java is an OOP programming language while JavaScript is an OOP scripting language.
- Java creates applications that run in a virtual machine or browser while JavaScript code is run on a browser only.
- Java code needs to be compiled while JavaScript code are all in text.

```js
function myFunction() {
            var count = 0;
            var x = document.getElementById("input1").hasAttribute("value");
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
            if (x) {
                count++;
            }
            alert(count);
        }
```

```html
    <input type="text" id="input1" value="sample" />
    <button id="myBtn" onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
    <p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: Thank you. I am executing JavaScript from JAVA code. Am sure there is some problem with this snippet `return (boolean) js.executeScript("$(arguments[0]).hasAttribute($(arguments[1]))", element, attr);`.....element is the WebElement and attr is the attribute which I want to search in the element and js is the JavaScriptExecutor